# How to automate creating 1500 Google Cloud VM Instances?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, automation

I need to create 1500 GCP VM instances all with the same configurations. How can I automate this process? With python or any easy way?

Comment: Google Cloud Projects have `quotas`. For Compute Engine this is broken down into resource types such as vCPUs. A typical quota will limit you to 24 vCPUs. There are other limits such as the quota for IP addresses. To launch 1500 virtual machines will require credit approval from Google Cloud Billing and I am not sure that you can in a single Google Cloud Project. Technically, you can use many products to automate launching resources. Terraform, Google Deployment Manager, or your favorite language using the client libraries or REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Python for that. More specifically, you would be using GCP's [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs) and specifying the desired configuration in the file written with Python.

The configuration can be specified in either `.yaml`, `.jinja` or `.py` formatted files - Google recommends using Python for complex deployments such as these. You can find a sample deployment of multiple Compute Engine instances [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/templates/vm_multiple_instances.py). Edit the configuration file according to your project and your needs and you should be good to go.

There are other ways of achieving it like creating an [Instance Template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-instance-template) and the scripting a `gcloud` CLI command to create instances from it, but that is assuming the configuration is indeed the same for all the instances and it can also become rather cumbersome to maintain, especially when Google already provides you with Deployment Manager and its features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think using an instance group to create multiple instances is easier.

Comment: @saurabhShah [Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) are meant more for balancing and maintaining workloads that can be autoscaled, autohealed and autoupdated in an application, if those are your needs then by all means go for it. Also don't confuse Instance Groups with Instance Templates. An Instance Template is just the template the Instance Group will be based on.

Comment: @saurabhShah Otherwise, if you need to automate a deployment (which is the exact definition of a Deployment Manager use case), then that's more approriate. If you're struggling in understanding it, Google provides a [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/quickstart) and you can usually find a lot of information in the docs. [Here's](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template) another one that tackles it when specifically using Python.